# "Mobilize Trike units" - A trike?

Tags: meaning, sarcasm, german

I heard a phrase from a movie "Captain America: The Winter Soldier". It is "Mobilize Trike Units".

In German, 'trike' is 'Dreirad'. I know that 'trike' is short for 'tricycle'.

Though, in the movie those Trike Units do look a lot older. No-one has a trike.

Is it a kind of joke?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he says **strike units**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a common term "strike units" which refers to a "unit" of people that can "strike" the enemy. This is likely what was said.

Although, there is a video game and accompanying show/movie called Dune 2000 in which there are "Trikes." In this case Trike means "Fast and lightly armored" it is "Used as a support unit for an infantry squad."

Comment: I googled strike and found a passable translation. Indeed it looks like it sais Strike not Trike.

Comment: @Grim yeah "strike forces" are common military units.